# How can I get data from an API that uses OAuth2.0 authentication when I have the Client Id and the Client Secret? (Brightscript)

Tags: oauth-2.0, restful-authentication, roku, brightscript

I am trying to authenticate into an API that uses OAuth2.0.  I have the Client ID and the Client Secret.  How can I get a Bearer token from the authentication server using Brightscript?

Comment: Would need to see some snippets from the api.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this API [URL](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication)

```
https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client
```

After that you have to use Basic Authorization:

> Username -> Client Id (Client Identifier)
>
> Password -> Client Secret(Client Secrets )

you can get these two after creating an app using this [link](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/new?source=topnav)

After that you have to set your header to:

```
[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]
```

and your body to::

```
[{"key":"grant_type","value":"client_credentials","description":""},{"key":"scope","value":"public private video_files","description":""}]
```

when you hit this on Postman you will get the access_token.